# itemSummary.getItemData() returns null occasionally

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the java API version 10.2. Here's how I obtain the ItemSummary:

```
   DataExtent dataExtent = new DataExtent();
   dataExtent.setStartLevel(0);
   dataExtent.setEndLevel(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   ItemSummary itemSummary =
       Util.getDataService().getItemSummaryForItem1(myContext,
       new Long(myItemId), dataExtent);
```

itemSummary is returned with a 0 status and the correct containerType of BANK. But itemSummary.getItemData() is sometimes null. I say sometimes because if I use the same itemId after a period of time, getItemData() is no longer null (which it should't be). There seem to be an issue if I perform a removeService, addService and getItemData() in quick succession. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When you do addService yodlee has to go to the bank's website and grab the data. Hence until yodlee has the data you will not have anything in ItemData.
You can call the [isItemRefreshing](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/isItemRefreshing) API  which will tell you if the item added has finished refreshing and once it does, then if you get the itemSummay and if the item was successfully refreshed then itemData should not be null